# Private class member is required when stubbing class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to stub out a class for a test I'm writing, but I am getting errors that private members are missing. This is surprising to me. I would have expected typescript to only care about the public members, as these are the only ones accessible from the outside.

`Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: () => number; }' but required in type 'MyClass'.(2741)`

```js
class MyClass {
    private a() {
        return 1
    }

    public b() {
        return 2
    }
}

const test: MyClass = {
    b: () => 2
}
```

[Typescript Playground implementation here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=288#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQA4CcBLANzABcBTaMACgEp0sdn8KyBXfAO2gEYnsAXwwC87AEYhCwaOPqNmLNpx4AmUcOEZgAey4Qy0SgYBccJChgBeBTnFn5VgHzR1WoA)

Why would typescript require me to implement private members in this case?

How would you work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workable answer here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18499#issuecomment-429272545

```js
class MyClass {
    private a() {
        return 1
    }

    public b() {
        return 2
    }
}


type Public<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }

const test: Public<MyClass> = {
    b: () => 2
}
```

This still feels super unnecessary. I don't know why typescript would require private members to be implemented. There's no way to access them. But at least I can work around it.